# Boolean array initialization in C

Tags: c, arrays

I've stumbled upon some weird behavior for which I couldn't find any info online. If I initialize a boolean array like this:

```
 bool condition[10] = {true,[5]=true};
```

I get the output I expect, first and sixth values are true while others are false. But if I write following snippet:

```
 bool condition[10] = {true,condition[5]=true};
```

I get first, SECOND and sixth values as true. I assume it's some kind of undefined behavior but I'd like someone more knowledgeable than me to explain to me what's going on.

I'm compiling with extra warning flags, using GCC and "-std=gnu99", and I'm not getting any errors.

Comment: The value of the expression can be used to initializer in C99. `condition[5]` also is available at this timing.

Comment: Yeah, but shouldn't it just flip second value and stop there? Why is it flipping 6th or whichever value i specify on top of it(as if I'm typing {true,condition[5],[5]=true})?

Comment: You're asking why is it setting condition[5] to true when you explicitly set it to true ... strange. But you're right that it's UB, since *when* that assignment occurs isn't specified.

Comment: Nope, i figured as much that it will modify second value, I'm asking why is it modifying second value AND 6th value. AFAIK it should stop after flipping second value to true. Basically Ouah explained what is going on, I just wanna know why is it happening.

Comment: Yep. condition[5] is the 6th value. Again, you explicitly set it. "Basically Ouah explained what is going on, I just wanna know why is it happening" -- that makes no sense ... explaining what is going on is the same as explaining why it's happening. "I'm not getting any errors" -- undefined behavior doesn't require diagnostics.

Comment: "explaining what is going on is the same as explaining why it's happening" Not exactly, I suspected that second value was evaluated to true, but I couldn't see why 6th value would be updated if that snippet of code was already executed. To me it looked as if for example both IF and ELSE were executed at same time. I hope I'm making it clear.

Comment: Again, you **explicitly set condition[5]=true** ... that's why it's true. You *also* set condition[1] to true by initializing it with a true value. "To me it looked as if for example both IF and ELSE were executed at same time. " -- No, you're just not thinking about this clearly. As ouah has explained, the setting of condition[5] can happen **after** the array is initialized (as is the case for you), or not ... it's underspecified by the standard.

Comment: I see, so basically condition[5]=true is setting first value to true and then doing what its supposed to do. Thanks, I couldn't wrap my mind around it,I guess I need my morning coffee to function!

Comment: Correct. But it doesn't have to ... it could set condition[5]=true *before* doing the implicit [5]=0 (because you didn't specify an initializer for that element). It's undefined behavior.

Comment: `condition[5]=true` is an *assignment*. It assigns the value `true` to `condition[5]`. It also yields the value `true`, which is used to initialize `condition[1]`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

C says that:

> (C11, 6.7.9p23) "The evaluations of the initialization list                expressions are indeterminately sequenced with  respect to one another and thus the order in which any side effects occur is unspecified."

and in C99

> (C99, 6.7.8p23) "The order in which any side effects occur among the initialization list expressions is unspecified."

That means that the declaration

```
    bool condition[10] = {true,condition[5]=true};
```

can have the same behavior:

```
    bool condition[10] = {true, 1};
```

or as

```
    bool condition[10] = {true, 1, [5] = true};
```

whether `condition[5] = true` evaluation is done before or after the `0` initialization of the array members.

**EDIT**: there is a case of unspecified initialization order of array elements in Defect Report #208. The case is different because in the DR example there are two initializers for a single element.

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/9899tc1/n32074.htm

> int a [2] = { f (0), f (1), [0] = f (2) };
>
> It was the intention of WG14 that the call f(0) might, but need not, be made when a is initialized. If the call is made, the order in which f(0) and f(2) occur is unspecified (as is the order in which f(1) occurs relative to both of these). Whether or not the call is made, the result of f(2) is used to initialize a[0].

Comment: Ok that answers it. One more question, why is condition[5]=true evaluated twice?

Comment: Do you have a reference for that behaviour? Why doesn't the initializer "overwrite" the assigned value? (I think I can sort of see it: The initializer *always* determines the inital value, and *any* modification has to happen after initialization. But this is confusing to look at.)

Comment: Thanks. It feels like there should be an example like that in the standard. The standard is full of bizarre corner case examples to illustrate those points...

Comment: I think your quote only applies to the side effects of all the initializers among each other, not to the ordering of the those effects with respect to the initialization itself?

Comment: @KerrekSB I agree, I think a second quote I needed, I'm searching it.

Comment: Want to hazard a guess about `condition[10] = { true, condition[0]=false }`?

Comment: I think @KerrekSB is right: It is unspecified whether `true` or `condition[5]=true` is evaluated first, but as they don't affect each other, it doesn't matter. `[0]` will be set to `true` and `[1]` will be set to the result of `condition[5]=true`, and as an assignment as an expression has the value assigned, `[5]=true` happens before `[1]=true`, and `[0]=true` habbens before or after that.

Comment: @JimBalter Right, in this case the result is probably unspecified.

Comment: @glglgl If that one is then so is the original one, from the cited section of the standard ... the order of the initializations isn't specified.

Comment: @glglgl "[5]=true happens ..." -- but there's no such thing here; there's an implicit [5]=false ... all members not explicitly initialized are initialized to 0.

Comment: "a similar case" -- no, sorry, there's no similarity between these cases ... the defect report (which is not in fact a defect, which is why the standard will only have a footnote added) is about a quite different matter.

Comment: @JimBalter agree, I edited my answer before seeing your comment.

Comment: `bool condition[10] = {true, 0, [5] = true}; ...  bool condition[10] = {true, 0};` -- no, there's no way it can be evaluated that way -- the second initializer is definitively true. It's only the final value of condition[5] that is uncertain because of the implicit `[5]=0` initializer.

Comment: "agree" -- But you say it's close; it's not, because there's no explicit setting of elements of a in that case ... [0] = expr is not like or close to a[0] = expr. In the DR, there are two initializers for a[0] and the later one overrides the earlier one. Here, there is just one initializer for each of [0] and [1], and none for [5].

Comment: @JimBalter yes, not even close, I reformulated the edit.

Comment: @JimBalter regarding the `condition[1]` value after the declaration, there is nothing yet in the Standard that convinces me it cannot be `0`.

Comment: How can it possibly be 0 when the value of the initializer (`condition[5]=true`) is true? Again, it's only the value of [5] that is underspecified, not the value of [1].

Comment: Ah, ok, I thought it was more complicated than that. :-) This one is certainly a puzzler! +1 for the effort to craft an accurate answer to this difficult question.

Comment: Can the behaviour differ on different calls to the function containing this code?

Comment: So, this would have been undefined behaviour in C99 (which didn't have *indeterminately sequenced* - two writes to the same variable without a sequence point is UB), but unspecified in C11?

Comment: @MattMcNabb In unspecified behavior, the way the implementation makes does not have to be the same each time. I see the C11 sentence quote as the rewording / clarification of the C99; both C99 and C11 behaviors are unspecified.

Answer (score 10):

That is a nice little puzzle. I think ouah got it, but more explanation would probably help. I think condition[5]=true is *not* a designated initializer. It is an expression, which evaluates to true as usual. Since that expression is in the second spot, true gets assigned to to condition[1]. Also, as a side-effect of the expression, condition[5] gets set to true.